# What is the difference in meaning between postposition "causa" and preposition "propter"?

Tags: word-comparison, semantics, synonyms

What is the difference in meaning between the postposition "causa" and the preposition "propter"? Both mean "because", right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference between *causa* and *propter* is that

- *propter* refers to an existing objective cause or motivation for something;
- *causa* refers to an intended purpose of an action, to be realised in the future. You can perhaps translate it as "for the sake of."

For example, you say *exempli causa*, meaning "to serve as an example, for instance." You don't say *propter exemplum*, or, if you do, it means "because of some example (that was given earlier)." *Causa* is also frequently used with possessives, like *mea, tua, vestra, nostra causa* etc., "for my, your, our sake."

On the other hand you say *propter timorem signa ferre nolebant*, "they would not bear the standards out of fear." You would not say *timoris causa*.

But I should note that the distinction is not always clear and is not strictly adhered to at all times.

Note: *causa* is not a postposition, it is simply a noun in the ablative, and while it is very regularly found in second position, there are exceptions to that rule.

Comment: Are you sure you are not confusing "causa" with "gratia"?

Comment: @FlatAssembler yes, pretty sure, although *causa* is indeed similar to *gratia* in this regard. De quo quidem non rogavisti.